# Fast space partitioning heuristic?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, computational-geometry, heuristics

I have a (sub)space that's populated with `N` line segments. These line segments are always part of a convex polygon. It might look like this:

[image]

What I want to do is develop a heuristic for selecting a line segment for splitting the space. The selected segment's supporting line will then split the space. There are two heuristic factors that work against each other:

1. The line segment should split the space evenly; there should be as many line segments in subspace A as in subspace B when done (***balance***)
2. The line segment's supporting line should intersect (split) as few other line segments as possible (***freedom***)

An example:

[image]

*Blue line:* Perfect freedom, very bad balance.

*Red line:* Very bad freedom, mediocre balance.

*Green line:* Bad freedom, excellent balance.

*Purple line:* Good freedom, decent balance.

In the above example the combined heuristic might select the purple line.

Now I could just loop through each line segment and compare it to every other line segment (seeing which ones it intersects and how balanced they are on each side). But this takes `O(N^2)` operations. I would prefer something that runs in `O(N log N)`.

Any ideas on an `O(N log N)` algorithm that loops through the line segments and gives them a score? One idea I had is to sort the segments three times and form some quadrants:

[image]

The quadrant center gives an idea where most line segments are. So maybe use them to find a line segment near this center and check if its orientation is OK in reference to the quadrants. Somehow. This would give an okay balance score.

For intersection I thought about creating bounding boxes for the segments and sorting them into a tree, thus maybe speeding up intersection estimation?

Some additional hints (what my input data looks like a lot of the time)

1. Most segments are axial (pure X or Y orientation)
2. Most segments are small compared to their spread.

Thanks for any new ideas or insights - the smallest hint of a data structure or strategy would help greatly!

Comment: Looks like a Binary Space Partition Tree problem. Don't quiet remember any heuristics for this. There is one common for kd-trees, called SAH (surface area heuristic). That can give you ideas how cost functions work in relation to finding an optimal solution during subdivision.

Comment: Yep it's for BSP construction. Helpful data structures indications there though, thanks!

Comment: In your algorithm. do you care about line direction? If it's for a BSP construction, then it feels like the direction of subsequent lines should not be picked independently from each other. You probably want every next line to be more or less perpendicular to the previous choice. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### **SOLUTION**

I've found a heuristic that works great for my BSP tree purposes and which is also really interesting to analyze. In the code below, I first tried using a AABB tree to ask "which segments does this line intersect." But even this was too slow, so in the end I just went with a costly initial `O(N^2)` comparison algorithm that quickly speeds up as the BSP tree builds, using a somewhat clever observation!

- Let each BSP node keep track of which line segments it still has left inside its subspace (and which it has to choose the next splitter from).
- Let each segment have four values associated to it: `posCount`, `negCount`, `introduced` and `saved`. Let it also have a `partner` reference to another segment, in case it was split (otherwise it is `null`).
- Initialize the splitters at the root node (that is, ALL of them) with the following `O(N^2)` algo:

Algorithm `calcRelationCounts(splitters S)`: `O(N^2)`

```
for all splitters s in S
    s.posCount = s.negCount = s.introduced = s.saved = 0
    for all splitters vs in S
        if (s == vs) continue
        if vs is fully on the positive side of the plane of s
            s.posCount++
        else if vs is fully on the negative side of the plane of s
            s.negCount++
        else if vs intersects the plane of s
            s.negCount++, s.posCount++, s.introduced++
        else if vs is coplanar with s
            s.saved++
```

- For each node with splitters still left, select the one which maximizes the following:

Algorithm `evaluate(...)` where `treeDepth = floor(log2(splitterCountAtThisNode))`: `O(1)`

```
evaluate(posCount, negCount, saved, introduced, treeDepth) {
    float f;
    if (treeDepth >= EVALUATE_X2) {
        f = EVALUATE_V2;
    } else if (treeDepth >= EVALUATE_X1) {
        float r = treeDepth - EVALUATE_X1;
        float w = EVALUATE_X2 - EVALUATE_X1;
        f = ((w-r) * EVALUATE_V1 + r * EVALUATE_V2) / w;
    } else {
        f = EVALUATE_V1;
    }

    float balanceScore = -f * BALANCE_WEIGHT * abs(posCount - negCount);
    float freedomScore = (1.0f-f) * (SAVED_WEIGHT * saved - INTRO_WEIGHT * introduced);
    return freedomScore + balanceScore;
}
```

With the following magic numbers that my optimization algorithm used:

```
#define BALANCE_WEIGHT 437
#define INTRO_WEIGHT 750
#define SAVED_WEIGHT 562
#define EVALUATE_X1 3
#define EVALUATE_X2 31
#define EVALUATE_V1 0.0351639f
#define EVALUATE_V2 0.187508f
```

- Use this splitter as the splitter for this node, call it SEL. Then, divide all the splitters at this node into three groups `positives`, `negatives` and `remnants`:

Algorithm `distributeSplitters()`:

```
for all splitters s at this node
    s.partner = null
    if s == SEL then add s to "remnants"
    else
        if s is fully on the positive side of SEL
            add s to "positives"
        else if s is fully on the negative side of SEL
            add s to "negatives
        else if s intersects SEL
            split s into two appropriate segments sp and sn
            sp.partner = sn, sn.partner = sp
            add sn to "negatives", sp to "positives" and s to "remnants"
        else if s coplanar with SEL
            add s to "remnants"

// the clever bit
if (positives.size() > negatives.size())
    calcRelationCounts(negatives)
    updateRelationCounts(positives, negatives, remnants)
else
    calcRelationCounts(positives)
    updateRelationCounts(negatives, positives, remnants)

add positives and negatives to appropriate child nodes for further processing
```

The clever thing I realized here is that, often, particularly the first couple of splits with the above heuristic, will produce very unbalanced splits (but very free). The problem is then that you get "`O(N^2) + O((N-n)^2)" + ...` which is horrible when `n` is small! Instead, I realized that instead of doing this, we can hard-recalculate the smallest split which takes `O(n^2)` which is not bad, and then simply iterate through each bit split splitter, subtracting counts from the smaller split part, which takes only `O(Nn)` which is much better than `O(N^2)`! Here is the code for `updateRelationCounts()`:

Algorithm `updateRelationCounts()`:

```
updateRelationCounts(toUpdate, removed, remnants) {
    for all splitters s in toUpdate
            for all splitters vs in removed, then remnants
                if vs has a partner
                    if the partner intersects s
                        s.posCount++, s.negCount++, s.introduced++
                    else if the partner is fully on the positive side of s
                        s.posCount++
                    else if the partner is fully on the negative side of s
                        s.negCount++
                    else if the partner is coplanar with s
                        s.saved++
                else
                    if vs intersects s
                        s.posCount--, s.negCount--, s.introduced--
                    else if vs is fully on the positive side of s
                        s.posCount--
                    else if vs is fully on the negative side of s
                        s.negCount--
                    else if vs is coplanar with s
                        s.saved--
```

I've tested this carefully now, and it seems that the logic is correct in that the update correctly modifies `posCount` etc. so that they are the same as they would be if they were hard-calculated again!